# two v-navigation-drawer side by side

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Im trying to have two app navigation drawers side by side, like [this](https://ibb.co/YWJzKDt)

But I cant make it work. I tried to wrap them in a grid to make them appeare side by side, but they seem to be under each other. How do I flip the second navigation-drawer next to the other?

```
    <v-container>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="6">
      <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        app
        class="Carbon"
        :src="'./nav/' + randomPic"
      >
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="6">
      <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        app
        class="Carbon"
        :src="'./nav/' + randomPic"
      >
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use grid. Just put them inside `<v-layout></v-layout>` and remove the `app`. Like this:

```html
  <v-layout>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model='drawer'
      class='Carbon'
      :src="'./nav/' + randomPic"
    >
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model='drawer'
      class='Carbon'
      :src="'./nav/' + randomPic"
    >
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-layout>
```

Comment: thank you, is there way to do this with prop `app`  Id like to keep them as `app`?

Comment: You can put each of the ``<v-navigation-drawer></v-navigation-drawer>`` into ``<v-app></v-app>`` tag individually.